# Resolving Promise <pending>

Tags: javascript, async-await, es6-promise

I'm looking to create a simple helper function which returns the hash for a given password using `bcrypt` but everytime i call the function, it resolves to `Promises { <pending> }` what am i doing wrong?

```
const saltPassword = async (password) => {
    const newHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) return err;
        return hash;
    });
    return await newHash;
}
```

cheers

Comment: `saltPassword` is a promise, so you need to use `then` on it to get the value via a callback. That is how async code works. You cannot expect to get a function return value that only arrives later when the function has already returned. NB: the second `await` is useless.

Comment: remove the `await` from the `return` statement.

Comment: `async` functions always return promises. So you either need to call `saltPassword` from an async function and await it, or learn how to work with promises.

Comment: @trincot In this case, both `await`s are useless because OP isn't doing anything with `newHash` other than returning it.

Comment: you can shorten the whole function to `const saltPassword = async (password) => bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds);` But this doesn't change anything about the async nature of this task and that you have to deal with the promise

Comment: or you use `const saltPassword = (password) => bcrypt.hashSync(password, saltRounds);` asuming that you use either [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) or [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this

```js
const saltPassword = async (password) => {
  const newHash = await bcrypt.hash(password, saltRounds, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) return err;
    return hash;
  });
  return newHash; // no need to await here
}

// Usage
const pwd = await saltPassword;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to return a Promise in order to use `await`. Simply wrap the callback function and call reject if there is an error or resolve if it was successful.

```
const saltPasswordAsync = (password, rounds) =>
    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      bcrypt.hash(password, rounds, (err, hash) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else resolve(hash)
      });
    });


async function doStuff() {
  try {
    const hash = await saltPasswordAsync('bacon', 8);
    console.log('The hash is ', hash);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('There was an error ', err);
  }
}

doStuff();
```

Now you can use `await` to wait on the promise to resolve and use the value. To catch an error, wrap with a try/catch statement.

***UPDATE***

Thomas pointed out that you may not need to wrap the callback in a promise, since bcrypt returns a promise if you do not pass a callback function. You could replace the call to `saltPasswordAsync` above with `bycript.hash` like so:

```
const hash = await bcrypt.hash('bacon', 8);
console.log('The hash is ', hash);
```

Comment: @Thomas Thanks! I updated my answer. I've never used bcrypt and the OP didn't mention which implementation they are using so I'll leave both options.